# Expanded accordion on the top

Tags: extjs, accordion

How to put expanded accordion on the top of other accordions programmatically? I know that you can do it using `activeOnTop:true`, property but I am wondering if it's possible to make it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can listen for accordions `expand` event and use accrodions container `insert()` method.

Code example (in your controller):

```
'myAccrodionsContainer myAccrodion': {
    expand: this.moveAccrordionToTop
}

...

moveAccrodionToTop: function(accordion) {
    var accordionsContainer = accordion.up('myAccordionsContainer');

    accrodionsContainer.insert(0, accrodion);
}
```

Insert method will handle all movement / render logic.

*If you want working fiddle just let me know and ill make it later*